# Expo - reduce PDF filesize on iOS devices

Tags: ios, react-native, pdf, expo

I'm currently creating an A4 PDF within my Expo-App, using the "expo-print" API ([printtofileasync](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/print/#printprinttofileasyncoptions)). The PDF includes images (photos taken from the device) and some text. I've set the PDF size to 595 width, 842 height (A4 dimensions). Unfortunately the size of the PDF is too large for my requirements (1,9MB with only 1 image).

I was able to reduce the PDF size on Android by decreasing the image size, but that does not work on iOS. I have the suspicion that on iOS Expo is simply "making screenshots" of the page, therefore changing the image size has no effect. 
I've already tried to decrease the whole PDF size to A5, but that's not a solution, because the PDFs needs to be printed afterwards on A4.

Any help would be appreciated!

Update: currently this my code:

```
const { uri, base64 } = await Print.printToFileAsync({
    width: 595,
    height: 842,
    html: 'data...',
    base64: true,
});

Share.share({
    url: 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem, I change my pdf creator because html creates variable size pdf and it depends on the resolution device, I use [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) it works in javascript, you can create or modify pdf, I write small example in Expo , I plan to create a library to do
Additional, you can [fill PDF](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/issues/109)
NOTE: it similar to [react-native-pdf-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf-lib) but working in only enviroment javascript

My App.tsx example:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import { Asset } from "expo-asset";
import * as Print from "expo-print";
import { degrees, PDFDocument, rgb, StandardFonts } from "pdf-lib";

export default function App({ context }: any) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button
        title="Generate PDF"
        onPress={async () => {
          const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
          /* const templateUri = Asset.fromModule(
            require("./assets/template.pdf")
          );
          console.log(templateUri); */
          const url =  'https://pdf-lib.js.org/assets/with_update_sections.pdf' // templateUri.uri
          req.open("GET", url, true);
          req.responseType = "blob";
          /*   req.onprogress = e => (t.progress = e.loaded); */
          req.onload = () => {
            const blob = req.response;
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            reader.onloadend = async function() {
              const base64data = reader.result as string; // template pdf in base64
              const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(base64data);
              const helveticaFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(
                StandardFonts.Helvetica
              );

              const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();
              const firstPage = pages[0];
              const { width, height } = firstPage.getSize();
              console.log(width, height);
              firstPage.drawText('This text was added with JavaScript!', {
                x: 5,
                y: height / 2 + 300,
                size: 50,
                font: helveticaFont,
                color: rgb(0.95, 0.1, 0.1),
                rotate: degrees(-45),
              });

              const pdfDataUri = await pdfDoc.saveAsBase64({ dataUri: true });
              Print.printAsync({ uri: pdfDataUri });
            };
          };
          req.onerror = console.error;
          req.send();
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

Comment: i used this library to create pdf ("pdf-lib") in my react native app. form where i could see this downloaded filein my  simulator. i am using simulator to run this application so when i click create pdf how can i know it is created or not? if it is created from where  should i get that file? i am using "Create Document" code of https://pdf-lib.js.org/.

Comment: Khushi If you using Expo, you can using expo-print or with react native cli, you can use react-native-pdf

Comment: Depende, if you only working with iOS with expo you can use react-native-webview to render PDF but not working same in Android,  if you want increase performance and control the PDF's, you must be eject expo and use react-native-pdf.

Comment: i am working with both android and ios. and  my server side is nodejs so i am trying to create pdf from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `base64` string and decoding it back to the pdf file. i think it should be of smaller size, Follow along.

1. Use Expo Print API to get the pdf file in question, remember to set the base64 to true.

```
import * as Print from 'expo-print';

const pdf = Print.printToFileAsync({
    width: 612,    // <=== your width
    height: 612,   // <=== your height
    base64: true
});
```

2. You can use [this](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/base64) or [this](https://github.com/eranbo/react-native-base64) library to decode back the base64 file.

```
import * as Print from 'expo-print';
import base64 from 'base64'; // or import base64 from 'react-native-base64'

const pdf = Print.printToFileAsync({
     width: 612,    // <=== your width
     height: 612,   // <=== your height
     base64: true
});

const pdfDecoded = base64(pdf);
```

The `pdfDecoded` will hold your new pdf file and it should be of smaller size, you can either send it to your server or display it.

I have not tested this just my 2 cents.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: We are already using base64, because we use this for the share API and we want to share the PDF via Email. I've tried the library as suggested, but it didn't help to reduce the filesize. 
`const { uri, base64 } = await Print.printToFileAsync({
    width: 595,
    height: 842,
    html: 'data...',
    base64: true,
});

Share.share({
    url: 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64,
});`